# How do I position my layout to have my aside next to my section?

Tags: html, css

Below my nav bar, I would like an aside on the left and a section right next to the aside. My aside and section should be on the same line not overlapping. My section right now is below my aside on a new line. How can I fix this issue?

```css
header {
 color:black;
 text-align:center;
 padding:5px;
 display:block;
}

#wrapper {
 width: 700px;
 margin: 0 auto;

}

#nav {
 width:500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 list-style-type: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 display:block;
}

#nav {
  padding: 10px 0;
  width:500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display:block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 10px -12px #999;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #999;
   box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px #999;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#nav a {
 text-align:center;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 5px;
}

aside {
 padding:5px;
 height:200px;
 width:100px;
 display:block;
}

section {
 float:left;
 width:200px;
 padding:5px;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>Portfolio</header>


<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Multimedia</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<aside>
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
sdf
</aside>

<section>
sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `word-wrap`. Then you could:

1. Use `display: block` and `float:left`. https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/5cyp6tjh/
2. Use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: top`. https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/cdsjsvL3/

**EDIT**
If you want to center them, the best way would be to use a wrapper rather than fudging with widths. That will get you into trouble if you try to go responsive (mobile).

https://jsfiddle.net/abalter/2a86ac1t/

HTML and CSS:

```css
aside, section {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
    
#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <aside>
    sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs
    sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
    sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfs
    sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
    sdf
  </aside>
    
  <section>
    sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: How would I center both the aside and section?

Comment: this is what I'm looking for, just centered! Would appreciate knowing how to

Comment: Never mind. I just changed the width of the section and aside. Thanks

Comment: Edited with method to center. Feel free to accept this answer if it solve it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add `float:right;` in css for `<aside>` tag.

**OR**

You can move `<aside>` below to `section` and add `float:left;` in css.

```
aside {
 padding:5px;
 height:200px;
 width:100px;
 float:right;
}
```

**And**

Use `word-break: break-all;` for `aside` and `section` to prevent 
overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here that you have applied `display:block` to aside. To fix it use `float:left` or `display:inline-block` instead of `display:block`. like this

```
aside {
    padding:5px;
    height:200px;
    word-break: break-word;
    float:left;
}
```

To remove overlap. use `word-break: break-word;`

Comment: How can I have aside and section not overlap?

Comment: just use word-break: break-word;

Comment: remove width:auto, use word-break: break-word;

Comment: check the edited answer copy-paste the css as it is.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't seem to have fixed the problem. @AdityaPonkshe

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `display:block` from aside and change the width to 300px since the float element is are 200px so then it must have 300px so then it format correctly and it overcome the overlap problem

or

you can change the width to auto : `width:auto`
    aside {
        padding:5px;
      margin-right:30px;
        height:200px;
        width:300px;
        float:left;
    }

Comment: Sorry. But I still have an issue with it overlapping. I updated the JFiddle.